# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError related to Spark Graphframe bfs

Tags: java, apache-spark, out-of-memory, graphframes

The OutOfMemoryError appears after I call bfs 20+ times in this way:

```
list_locals = [] 
#g is the graphframe with > 3 million nodes and > 15 million edges. 

def fn(row): 
    arg1 = "id = '%s'" %row.arg1 
    arg2 = "id = '%s'" %row.arg2 
    results = g.bfs(arg1, arg2, maxPathLength = 4) 
    list_locals.append(results.rdd.collect()) 
    results = None 

# t is a list of row objects 
for i in range(101): 
    fn(t[i]) 
print i
```

From the logs, I can see that bfs created lots of broadcast variables and tried to clear them. I wonder whether the clearance of broadcast variables is not done completely? I have attached the most recent error messages below.  Thanks!

```
16/07/11 09:44:28 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed     broadcast_922_piece0 on dsg-cluster-server-s06.xxx:40047
```

in memory (size: 8.1 KB, free: 3.0 GB)

```
16/07/11 09:44:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_924 stored as values in memory (estimated size 24.4 KB, free 2.8 MB)                                                                     

Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMoryError: Java heap space
```

This is an exception in the driver process, you should increase your driver memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the driver memory was set to 32G, which should be more than enough. . set("spark.driver.memory", "16g")

Comment: Are you running in client mode (the default), because in client mode you have to set driver memory using -driver-memory when you submit the application.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is resolved. I am running in client mode and set the spark.driver.memory through submit argument.

Comment: @Yiliang hey how did you do that? i'm launching the spark app from Junit

Comment: @VasileSurdu I just put the option in the submit arg. Sorry, I just saw your message.